# Why "Bad request" in google drive.files.update using Python3.6 in Google Colaboratory?

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I use Google Drive API v3 and Python3.6 in Google Colaboratory. My guess, it is an  error in update_metadata, but I can't find it. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update
says these properties are writable. I'm stucked, and I need help, thanks.

```
def NEWshare(selected_id, email, permissions_metadata, emailmsg, send=True):                   
    drive_service.permissions().create(body=permissions_metadata,                                            
    emailMessage = emailmsg,
    sendNotificationEmail = send,
    fileId=selected_id).execute()

def NEWupdate(selected_id, update_metadata):
    drive_service.files().update(body=update_metadata, 
    fileId=selected_id).execute()

permissions_metadata = {
                        "deleted": True,
                        "emailAddress": email,
                        "kind": "drive#permission",
                        "role": "reader",
                        "type": "user"
                       }

update_metadata = {
                   "copyRequiresWriterPermission": True,
                   "writersCanShare": False
                  }
```

The NEWshare(selected_id, email, permissions_metadata, emailmsg, send=True) works well. Now I want to update with NEWupdate(selected_id, update_metadata), but I obtain the error message

```
HttpError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-07b373587193> in <module>()
----> 1 NEWupdate(selected_id, update_metadata)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/http.py in execute(self, http, num_retries)
    838       callback(resp)
    839     if resp.status >= 300:
--> 840       raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
    841     return self.postproc(resp, content)
    842 

HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1n8k_4fY4KMM9gnqD2MPvvV8cRgY0yCRd?alt=json returned "Bad Request">
```

Comment: For this error "`HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1n8k_4fY4KMM9gnqD2MPvvV8cRgY0yCRd?alt=json returned "Bad Request">`", a refresh request needs `refresh_token`, `client_id`, `client_secret`, and `grant_type`. Here is the documentation on [refreshing an access token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline). See [this github post](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/605).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this error "`HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1n8k_4fY4KMM9gnqD2MPvvV8cRgY0yCRd?alt=json returned "Bad Request">`", a refresh request needs `refresh_token`, `client_id`, `client_secret`, and `grant_type`. Here is the documentation on [refreshing an access token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline). See [this github post](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/605).